# What should I look for to replace the iSight camera on a 2010 13" Macbook Pro with a modern retina style FaceTime HD camera?

Tags: macbook-pro, facetime, webcam

Given that I have a 13" 2010 Macbook Pro with the old low-res iSight camera, is it possible to upgrade that camera to a modern FaceTime HD camera like the kind in the modern retina Macbook Pro.

I'm curious if I should look for a particular part number or maybe this is just not supported and someone can save me the effort now before I go down a costly path of purchasing parts that could never work together.

How would you do this?

Comment: Have you found information supporting that such an "upgrade" is possible? I think that there are also driver and firmware issues that will probably prevent such an upgrade to work; at least not out-of-the-box...

Comment: as far as driver issues, this would be running Yosemite, so that shouldn't be an issue. I suspected that for firmware, this was going to be a USB cable internally, all things considered. That left "does the hardware work, is it compatible" and there really isn't a single site on the internet that can answer such a question, but this site is objective and the sort of place that can narrow that down. This is a real-world problem, not theoretical, so I thought I should ask.

Comment: It is always worth asking :-) However, getting an answer in this community may be proven difficult, unless someone has already done that. You may also want to consider electronics.stackexchange.com or even superuser. Good luck and keep us posted if you try!